# PHP MD5 hashing

Tags: c#, php, md5

i have a hashing algorithm in C#, in a nutshell, it is:

```
string hashCode = string.Empty;
        if (null != password)
        {
            System.Security.Cryptography.MD5 cryptography = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] code = cryptography.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(password));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            // Converting the code to string.
            for (int i = 0; i < code.Length; i++)
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(code[i].ToString("x2"));
            }

            hashCode = stringBuilder.ToString();
        }

        return hashCode;
    }
```

Now I need to replicate this behaviour in php.....
Thanks in advance...

**NOTE:** I cannot change C# behaviour because it's already implemented and passwords saved in my db with this algorithm.

Comment: What is your question? You want us to write the code for you? Or do you want some pointers? Also, use SHA instead of MD5 for encryption.

Comment: Guys, please, MD5 is NOT encryption.

Comment: PHP does this out of the box with a simple md5("your string here") function

Answer (score 3):

PHP has built in MD5 ability, you can put about anything in and get a hex string back, is this what you had in mind?

md5()

http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Answer (score 0):

SEE BELOW

[image: Encryption in PHP]